# 2 models with pivot table, many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot

I'm trying to create a blog and I have two models, Post and Tag. I want to connect both of them with a pivot table. It's a many to many relationship and I can't figure out how to link posts and tags together. when I try to do that, it returns nothing on my DB. Posts have a title and the content while tags only have the name.
I've read I have to use the sync method or attach-detach but I don't know where to do that. Is it on posts routes or tags routes? I have included the routes of posts and tags on routes.php grouping them by using:

```
Route::resource('/tags', 'TagController');

Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');
```

Here's what i have so far:

My Post model:

```
class Post extends Model{
protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'content'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'view_count'
];

public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tag');
}}
```

Here is my Tag model:

```
class Tag extends Model{
protected $fillable = [
    'name'
];

public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_tag');
}}
```

Here's my post_tag pivot table:

```
class CreatePostTagTable extends Migration{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('post_tag');
}}
```

Comment: Code looks good. What are you trying that doesn't work?

Comment: Well when I want to create a post, I want the only user, which is the admin, to associate whatever tags he wants to his post. What route should I create with the sync method to connect posts with tags, because so far my posts and my tags are stored when created, but nothing is stored in post_tag table

Comment: @joel hinz I now realize my crud looks good, but I have one unrelated question for you. Can I edit the hole question to ask how do I implement the tag checkbox in the post's create view?

Comment: Either that or add a new question. I don't think you can do any of this automatically, but it should be fairly easy to get the code going using e.g. the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thank you for your time @JoelHinz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there I was new too in laravel, and I have same problem with you. In your case I think the best practice is attach it in your `PostController.php`. Let me share the code for you, and I hope it can help

**PostController**

```php
public function store (Request $request) {

    // First we need to create variable that contain your tag_id
    // $tags = [1, 2, 4]; something like this
    $tags = $request->input('tags');



    // Now storing the data in posts table
    $post =  new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->content = $request->input('content');
    $post->save();

    //After save the post, we need to attach it
    $post->tags()->attach($tags);
}
```

**Edit: Add example view**

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="subscribeNews" name="tags[]" value="1">
    <label for="subscribeNews">Tag 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="subscribeNews" name="tags[]" value="2">
    <label for="subscribeNews">Tag 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="subscribeNews" name="tags[]" value="3">
    <label for="subscribeNews">Tag 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="subscribeNews" name="tags[]" value="n">
    <label for="subscribeNews">More tag</label>
  </div>
```

And then in **PostController.php** you can get the id if user check the checkbox:

```php
$tags = $request->input('tags');
```

**Edit2: Add example use sync**

Here, I give you little example on using sync, first let's set a post that have 5 tags on it. And in the end we just want to set it 3

```php
$post = Post::find(1) //get the post with id 1, this post have 5 tags
// Let's say that this post have 5 tags with this ids [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// And then admin edit this post and select the tag with id [1, 2, 6] we set it in $tags variable
$tags = $request->input('tags'); //[1, 2, 6]

// And the last we just need to use sync method like this
$post->tags()->sync($tags);

// After use that, it will detach the tag based from removed ids [3, 4, 5] and attach new tag if there's new tag id [6]
// And in the end the post just have 3 tags
```

Okay that is example logic, I still learn about it too, but I hope it can help you :D

Comment: can you please show me an example using sync()?
here's the thing. When the admin creates a new post or edits it, he can assign one or more tags to the post, whichever tag he wants. Also he has the right to create new tags. Isn't it better if the created tags get synced automatically? That way he can delete, create new tags and select one or more tags from the list.
p.s. I still haven't created the dropdown list of tags in my post create view

Comment: Ah I'm glad can help you :D

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sync()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) function, ex:

```
$post->tags()->sync($array_of_tags_ids)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to include only numbers as id? I don't know what tags the admin is going to choose for his post. Is there another way instead of creating the array with tag id?

Comment: @livia What do you have in mind? Because to set a relationship, just use the pivot table passing the id of both tags and post

Comment: When the admin creates a new post or edits it, he can assign one or more tags to the post, whichever tag he wants. Also he has the right to create new tags. Logically if I pass tag_id 1 or 3 or whatever, am I not forcing him to choose only between 1 or 3?